# A few questions about Dart generics and type safety

Tags: dart

I have the following Dart 2 code with null-safety.

```dart
extension Foo<T> on List<T> {
  List<U> bar<U>({
    U Function(T)? transform,
  }) {
    final t = transform ?? _identityTransform;
    return map(t).toList();
  }
}

U _identityTransform<T, U>(T t) => t as U; // #1, #2

void main() {
  final strings = ['a', 'b', 'c'].bar<String>(); // #3
  final ints = ['1', '2', '3'].bar(transform: int.parse);

  print(strings);
  print(ints);
}
```

It is an extension method on `List<T>` with a custom method that is basically a `map` with the
difference that it can return a new list of the same type if no `transform` is specified. (My real code is more complex than this, but this example is enough to present my questions.)

I want to be able to call `bar()` on a `List` with `transform` or without; if called without it, `_identityTransform` should be used.

The code above works, but I have a few reservations as to its quality, and questions, as I haven't really come to terms with Dart generics yet:

1. In the line marked #1 - the `_identityTransform` takes two generic parameters as I need access to them, but when the function is used the generic types are not used because I don't think it is possible to write something like `_identityTransform<T, U>` there. Is there a better way of defining `_identityTransform`? Am I losing any type safety with my current code?
2. In the line marked #2 I need a cast `as U` for the code to compile, I haven't managed to make the code work without it. Is there a way to do it without the cast?
3. In the line marked #3, when I call the extension method without any `transform` (i.e. I want the identity transform to kick in) I need to explicitly pass the generic type, otherwise the compiler complains about missing generic  type (in strong mode) or infers `strings` to be `List<dynamic>` (strong mode turned off). Is some generics magic possible to be able to call `.bar()` and still have `strings` be inferred to `List<String>`?

Comment: Ok I can see there are votes to close this issue as not focused enough. I changed the question a bit and it is now only about generics. Do you really want me to write 3 separate questions? Otherwise, any tips on how to make it good enough for people to actually answer and not just downvote and want to close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would make `_identityTransform` a nested function of `bar` so that you can remove its type arguments and instead use the same `T` and `U` as bar:

   ```dart
   extension Foo<T> on List<T> {
     List<U> bar<U>({
       U Function(T)? transform,
     }) {
       U _identityTransform(T t) => t as U;

       final t = transform ?? _identityTransform;
       return map(t).toList();
     }
   }
   ```

   Alternatively if you want to explicitly use `_identityTransform<T, U>`, then you could use a closure: `t = transform ?? (arg) => _identityTransform<T, U>(arg)`, but that seems like overkill.
2. You need the cast. `T` and `U` are independent/unrelated types. Since you don't know that you want `T` and `U` to be the same until `bar` checks its argument at runtime, you will need the explicit cast to satisfy static type checking.
3. If the caller passes nothing for the transform argument, there is nothing to infer `U` from, so it will be `dynamic`. I can't think of any magical way make `U` default to `T` in such a case (again, that would be known only at runtime, but generics must satisfy static analysis).

Comment: About #1 - I can use a closure but if I need one anyway there is not reason to have a separate `_identityTransform` in the first place.